# msi log: Something about Client State

Tags: logging, wix, windows-installer

> Component: ComponentName; Installed: Absent; Request: Local; Action: Local; Client State: Unknown

Help me please. Above you can see usual string from msi log. Where can I find information about **"Client State"**? Such as: "Unknown", "Null", "Not Used", etc.

Answer (score 0):

A google search for "windows installer component client state" is a pretty good start. See:

[About Shared Components](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2009/12/21/about-shared-components.aspx)

[MsiEnumClients function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370094%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Basically clients refers to products that share a component and have to do with component sharing.