# [Wix]What does it mean in installer log file: Client State: Absent

Tags: wix

Some components added to my msi-project are not installed during the installation.
The log file states:
Component: ; Installed: Local;   Request: Local;   Action: Local;   Client State: Absent

What does 'Client State: Absent' mean?

Comment: This has actually puzzled me as well. [There is an annotated MSI log from an MSI team member of old here](https://web.archive.org/web/20080916030949/http://www.rmacdonald.members.winisp.net/Blog_Docs/Annotated_Windows_Installer_Log.pdf), but it doesn't really say much about this particular issue. Not sure after reading [this answer either](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16837760/129130).  Could this have to do with components from merge modules shared by many MSI packages? What is the component in question for you? Does it have a GUID as part of its component name?

Comment: Thank you. I saw that comment too. It is a normal component with a guid like all the others. No merge module, no shared component.
I was looking for a documentation of this 'Client State', but I did not find any.